# How replace an optionally occuring prefix with regex

Tags: regex

I have a query string that can look like this:

```
    ?blah=1&phoneNum=123-456-7890
```

OR

```
    ?phoneNum=123-456-7890
```

I'm using this regex: phoneNum=[^&]+&? to remove the substring phoneNum=**__** from the query string, but it leaves a trailing & in the first case, which is no me gusta.

How do I adapt my regex pattern to optionally remove the preceeding &? so it removes both:

```
    phoneNum=123-456-7890
```

AND

```
    &phoneNum=123-456-7890
```

from the query string?

Comment: Could you tell us exactly what result you would like with the given inputs?

Comment: try using 

     `&?phoneNum=[^&]+&?`... 

Although i am not sure WHY you are splitting your own query string instead of using a query string parser. Are you writing your own parser? What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the way you made the last `&` optional using `?`, you can make the first one also optional:

```
&?phoneNum=[^&]+&?
```

Answer (score 1):

To strictly answer your question, you would prepend a &? to your regex, but I think it's a fragile approach, because the phoneNum param can potentially be anywhere in the query string: first, last or inbetween. If you ever start passing more parameters and you remove both & signs, you can end up with a messed up request.

I would parse the query, discard the phoneNumber parameter and construct the query again.